# Paste quoted elements into Excel without loosing quotes

Tags: excel, quotes

I'm trying to copy three lines of quoted words into Excel.

[image: Things to copy]

But when I paste them the quotes are automatically deleted!

[image: auto-deleted]

Does anyone know how to keep the quotation marks on Excel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Highlight the cells you want to add the quotes:

1. Right click Go to Format Cells –> Custom
2. Copy/Paste the following into the Type field: \”@\”
3. Click “okay”

Comment: Thank you for your answers. My question has been moved to here: https://superuser.com/questions/1657510/paste-quoted-elements-into-excel-without-loosing-quotes

Answer (score 0):

Option B formula:

1. Input formula `=CHAR(34) & F1 & CHAR(34)` into helper column i.e. Column 'G'
2. Select the formula and drag down your range of cells from G1 to G3 (based on your dataset having 3 examples above)